# ENV Behavior of Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Problem Statement**: Running a docker container from the below mentioned Dockerfile leads to an unexpected output for me. Can someone please explain:
=> Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV abc="one"

ENV abc="two" def=$abc

ENV ghi="three"

ENTRYPOINT echo $abc $def $ghi
```

=> **Output**: two one three

=> **Output-According-to-Me**: two two three

Can someone please explain out how is exactly is the behavior of docker in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker processing happen layer wise, thats why it doesn't know value of variable until the layer get completed.
This one is correct output : two one three